# how solve this error( Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is :

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME2
DECLARE @Number INT
DECLARE @Number2 INT

SET @Number = 90
SET @Number2 = 89

SET @Num = @Number - @Number2

SET @Date = SELECT TOP (@Num) YEAR(Tarikh) FROM Final
```

Comment: Could `Num` have a value greater than 1? Where is the `ORDER BY` in your query with `TOP`? If the answer to the former is "no" then use a subquery, if yes, you need to explain your goal; you can't set the value of a *scalar* variable to be many values.

Comment: ***WHY*** are you assining an `INT` value (from the `YEAR(...)` ) to a `DATETIME2` variable `@Date` ?!?!?!? That doesn't make any sense whatsoever.....

Answer (score 1):

You need to **either** put your `SELECT` subquery into brackets like this:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME2   -- this should *really* be an `INT` ....   
SET @Date = (SELECT TOP (@Num) YEAR(Tarikh) FROM Final)  -- YEAR(..) returns *INT* !
```

or you need to rewrite this as a `SELECT` only statement - like this:

```
SELECT TOP (@Num) @Date = YEAR(Tarikh) 
FROM Final 
-- ORDER BY ......   -- you should *REALLY* include an ORDER BY for TOP to make any sense....
```

Of course, this **only** works if your subquery always returns **only ONE** possible value!

**And also**: using the `TOP` clause *without* an explicit `ORDER BY` clause is kinda dangerous - since you're not explicitly telling SQL Server **which** `TOP` row you want, you might get any arbitrary row(s) ...

**And lastly**: using `YEAR(...)` returns an `INT` value - which you're assigning to a `DATETIME2` variable ...... that doesn't really make any sense at all.......

Comment: Even if it does only return one row, the value set will be an arbitrary one, and may not be the same each time you run the SQL. But if it can only return one, `@Number` and `@Number2` seems rather pointless in the OPs code.